# Trouble with if/then statements containing character variables in Fortran 77

Tags: if-statement, fortran, character, fortran77, word-count

I am currently trying to write a program in Fortran 77 that calculates the number of words in a text file. The text files looks like this:

Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world.       Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world.

My program currently looks like this:

```
       program COUNT
       implicit none

       character text*100000
       integer i, a, nw
       nw=1 !number of words                                                     

       open(9, FILE='file.txt', STATUS='old')
       read(9, '(A)') text

       a=0
  10   do i=1, LEN_TRIM(text)
          if (text(i:i) .ne. " ") then
             if (a .eq. 0) then
                goto 10
             else
                a=0
                nw=nw+1
                goto 10
             endif
          else
             if (a .eq. 0) then
                a=a+1
                goto 10
             else
                goto 10
             endif
          endif
       enddo

       print *, "Number of words: ", nw

       end
```

I did this on paper and it should work, however, my program is getting stuck in the do-loop. I think that this might have something to do with this statement:

```
       if (text(i:i) .ne. " ") then
```

Am I allowed to write the logical expression this way? If not, does anyone have any hints on how I could rewrite this code? I'm sorry if my program is a bit messy; I'm relatively new at this. I'm trying to improve my coding skills to do computational chemistry. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I suggest learning Fortran 95.  You have already used some of it: `len_trim`.  The free-form source layout is easier to use and the language has many additional capabilities.   See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features

Comment: You don't really need any of your goto 10s.  Alternatively if you want them in, change them to cycle (which means go to the next iteration).

Comment: I did not suggest `cycle`, bucause it is from Fortran 90.

Comment: `(Free-form + Lowercase keywords) /= Fortran 77`

Comment: I think that len_trim is a Fortran 77 function. M. S. B., I agree that Fortran 95 is easier to use, however, my computational materials science class next term is based in Fortran 77. I would much rather code in Fortran 95 or C/C++. cup, I removed the second and third gotos and replaced the first and last gotos with cycles. This made my program work. Vladimir F, you are also right that the gotos are unnecessary, however, I was able to fix the program with cycle. Kyle, I code in emacs so I do not have to worry about the free form issue but I believe Fortran 77 allows lowercase keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your if branches go to `goto 10` which points at the beginning of the loop. There is no way to end because this will restart the loop from the beginning. Do not use goto to start new iteration `end do` s meant for that.